# Array getting wrong amount of spaces

Tags: c++, arrays, class, operator-overloading

So I've been trying to write string class for learning purposes, and when I tried to overload the + operator I got the strangest problem: The array I've been trying to crate had 4 extra spaces, no matter what amount I tried to create it with (Also the entire thing crashed horribly). So for example, when I wrote:
newStr.length = this->length + other.length;
newStr.str = new char[newStr.length+1];
newStr.str kept having 4 more spaces than this->length + other.length + 1, and when I just left it at newStr.str = new char[1], the array still have been created with 5 cells for some reason. I've tried to write the entire class without ever creating "int length" but that didn't work, nor did any my attempts to isolate the array creation from class(It works normally when not in class and not working with these specific class objects so it's not some visual studio bug). I've tried everything I could think of, though I'm new at this and most likely missed something. Could anybody please help me? Here's the entire code for reference, it's not that long:

```
#include <iostream>
#define DEBUG
using namespace std;

class MyString
{
private:
    char* str;
    int length;
public:
    MyString() 
    {
        str = nullptr;
        length = 0;
    }
    MyString(const char *str)
    {
        length = strlen(str);
        this->str = new char[length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            this->str[i] = str[i];
        }
        this->str[length] = '\0';
    }
    ~MyString()
    {
        delete[] str;
    }
    MyString& operator =(const MyString& other)
    {
        if (this->str != nullptr) delete[] str;
        length = other.length;
        this->str = new char[length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            this->str[i] = other.str[i];
        }
        this->str[length] = '\0';
        return *this;
    }
    MyString operator +(const MyString& other)
    {
        MyString newStr;
        newStr.length = this->length + other.length;
        newStr.str = new char[newStr.length+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < this->length; i++)
        {
            newStr.str[i] = this->str[i];
        }
        for (int i = this->length; i < newStr.length; i++)
        {
            newStr.str[i] = other.str[i-strlen(this->str)];
        }
        newStr.str[newStr.length] = '\0';
        return newStr;
    }
    void Print()
    {
        cout << str;
    }
};



int main()
{
    MyString a("TESTY");
    MyString b("WUBBA");
    a = a + b;
    a.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand the issue. Expected results here: https://godbolt.org/z/M5vWazb74

Comment: How do you know that there are extra bytes?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't exhibit the problem you describe (see the online compiler output linked to above - there are no 4 extra spaces visible there). Please clarify your problem!